# How to style select option elements in Ionic for Android?

Tags: android, css, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic framework to build my application.  My application includes lots of select elements.

When I view the application on Android 4.4, the selects and their options look as expected.

When I view the application on Android 5.0 or 5.1, the text of the options is grey, which leads my users to think the options are disabled (they are not).

Ionic's documentation for the select css includes the following: "Ionic's select is styled so its appearance is prettied up relative to the browser's default style. However, when the select elements is opened, the default behavior on how to select one of the options is still managed by the browser."

Can anyone tell me how I can control the styling of the select options so they don't appear disabled?  Monkeying around with Ionic's css doesn't appear to change anything, and I'm guessing that's because Android is "styling" the element, rather than Ionic.

Thanks.

Comment: just add a css class on your own with background color or with an opacity property in your style.css